# SQL Server create a table

Tags: sql-server

Thanks for everybody , How can i create program for this problem. It will be helpful for me. I need to know create program for this to store data in SQL Server.

Thanks for your help, I am using twin cat 3 PLC program , my packet data like that 4144010203040506. I send data MS SQL server like that. when i send data is (arg ) for each column, but i want to store data arg4 to arg9 is one column.

```
arg 1:= F_STRING(Time stamp),arg 2:= F_byte(id) (41),arg 3:= F_byte(length) (44),arg 4:= F_string (read data [0]) (01),arg 5:= F_string (read data [1])(02),arg 6:= F_string (read data [2]) (03),arg 7:= F_string (read data [3]) (04),arg 8:= F_string (read data [4]) (05),arg 9:= F_string (read data [5]) (06).
```

Here arg 1 and arg 2 is not array type. its single byte value. And arg 4 to arg 9 string array type . now i want to store in data one table like this. my table structure. I want to store all data_value together one column one row .

```
  pd_time stamp                id   length   data_value 
    2016-06-18 18:24:28.153    41      44    010203040506
```

Comment: Your question is quite unclear, are you asking how to store the data or how to create a program?

Comment: SQL Server *doesn't* have an "array" datatype, and you *should not* store multiple pieces of data in single column (that **violates** the basic, first normal form of relational design) ....

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question, I think you should use a stored like this one..

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertDataIntoTable
    @dataToStore NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
declare @TS TIMESTAMP;
declare @ID INT;
declare @LN INT;
declare @DT NVARCHAR(50);

set @TS = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
set @ID = SUBSTRING(@dataToStore, 1,2);
set @TS = SUBSTRING(@dataToStore, 3,2);
set @TS = SUBSTRING(@dataToStore, 5,LEN(@dataToStore)-4);

INSERT INTO yourTableName 
    ( TS, Id, LN, Data )
VALUES
    ( @TS, @ID, @LN, @DT )
END
GO
```

Hope this helps

Dex

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to create table that will hold `timestamp`, `id`, `length` and `dataid`:

```
CREATE TABLE packet_data (
    pd_timestamp datetime NOT NULL,
    id int NOT NULL,
    [length] int NOT NULL,
    dataid int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_packet_data PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (dataid),
)
```

Then table that will hold data part:

```
CREATE TABLE main_data (
    dataid int NOT NULL,
    data_value nvarchar(10) NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT PK_main_data PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (dataid, data_value)
)
```

Then add FK:

```
ALTER TABLE main_data ADD
CONSTRAINT FK_main_data_packet_data FOREIGN KEY (dataid) 
    REFERENCES packet_data (dataid)
    ON DELETE CASCADE    
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

So you will get one-to-many relationship by `dataid` field to store your data normalized.

Then use SP to load data:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE add_data
    @string nvarchar(max) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @id int,
            @length int,
            @data_array nvarchar(max),@xml xml,
            @n int = 0, @i int = 0, @s int = 3,
            @current datetime = GETDATE()

    SELECT  @id = CAST(LEFT(@string,2) as int),
            @length = CAST(SUBSTRING(@string,3,2) as int),
            @data_array = RIGHT(@string,LEN(@string)-4)

    SELECT @n  = LEN(@data_array)/2 - 1

    WHILE @n > @i
    BEGIN
        SELECT @data_array = STUFF(@data_array,@s,0,'-')
        SET @i=@i+1
        SET @s=@s+3
    END

    SELECT @xml = CAST('<a>'+REPLACE(@data_array,'-','</a><a>') + '</a>' as xml)

    INSERT INTO packet_data ([pd_timestamp], [id], [length])
    VALUES (@current, @id, @length)

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[main_data]
    SELECT  @@IDENTITY,
            t.v.value('.','nvarchar(10)')
    FROM @xml.nodes('/a') as t(v)
END
```

If execute your SP like:

```
EXEC add_data N'4144010203040506'
```

You will get this in table `packet_data`:

```
pd_timestamp            id  length  dataid
2016-06-18 18:24:28.153 41  44      1
```

In table `main_data`:

```
dataid  data_value
1       01
1       02
1       03
1       04
1       05
1       06
```

Comment: Thanks for your help , i wrote my  program how to send data in database , please could you help me now .